# Split images from dataloader into patches

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, mnist

Using the Fashion mnist dataset, I don't want to just split a single image into patches but rather all of images.

I've seen the function unfold() but I think this only works for a single image

```py
mnist_train = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(
root="../data", train=True, 
transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]), download=True)

x = mnist_train[0][0][-1, :, :]

x = x.unfold(0, 7, 7).unfold(1, 7, 7)

x.shape
```

How do I make non-overlapping patches (of any number to keep it simple) for all images?

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom transform to split *all* images into multiple patches. Something along the lines of:

```
class Patch(object):
    """
    Creates patches from images
    """

    def __init__(self, patch_size=7):
        self.patch_size = patch_size

    def __call__(self, image):
        patched_image = # ... your code here
        return patched_image


mnist_train = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="../data", train=True,
    transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), Patch()]), download=True)
```